# how can I suspend and resume a node worker?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to suspend and resume a node worker? For worker, I mean a process created by using the [cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). 
A code example would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The node cluster module just wraps a set of processes created by the `child_process.fork` module. The main difference is if you look at the source for the `cluster` module's all the forks created use the current processes path for the `modulePath` argument when creating forks. My point
is that the `cluster` module is really an abstraction to handle workloads for you. So you may want to take a look at the `child_process` module.

That being said, I am unaware of ways to suspend and resume node processes, but you can set up communications betweeen processes with `process.on('message')` and `process.send()`.

For example, 2 files `master.js` and `worker.js`

worker.js

```
process.on('message', function(message) {
   process.send('Hey you sent ' + m);
});
```

master.js

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;

var worker = fork('./worker.js');

child.on('message', function(m) {
   console.log('Recieved: ' + m);
});

// we could send as many messages as we want, the child process will 
// will idle between messages
child.send('Message 1');
```

In this example we could send as many messages back and forth as we want, the child process will not exit because we have added event listeners to `process` but it will only be listening to the `message` event.

Comment: but i can't pause the execution of the worker. That's what i need.